# cancelling mouseup in jquery sortable to prevent lightbox from responding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

jQuery v1.7.1
jQuery UI 1.8.10
jquery-lightbox-0.5.js

Having a problem with jquery-ui sortable and lightbox co-existing in FireFox only (Chrome & IE not a problem). At the end of a drag-n-drop operation on an image in a list, sortable works correctly, but apparently fails to cancel the mouse-up event, so lightbox proceeds with opening the image. Is there anything I can do with sortable to ensure lightbox does not fire? alternately, can lightbox respond to click instead of mouseup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an isDragging variable and set it to true in the handler for sortable. Create a handler for the lightbox mouseup event and check if isDragging. If true cancel if false do nothing. Finally don't forget to set isDragging to false in the draggable stop event.

Comment: +1 Flag variables generally have less overhead than suppressing/modifying jQuery events.

Comment: essentially this is the right answer, although the behavior of the LightBox I am dealing with required me to hack into the start function rather than in a handler and set the flag to false whenever it was true and return